# QGIS - How to fill small gaps in line (other than the Vertex tool)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, gap

I suspect this is not as easy as it looks. On the pictured line (of which I have many others), is there a plug in or technique that creates a single line? or am I looking at an epic snap to vertex session?

[image: gappy line]

Comment: [`v.clean`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.clean.html), check this thread as well [How to connect lines with gaps to continuous line?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134472/how-to-connect-lines-with-gaps-to-continuous-line)